# Why is `(:)` built-in?

Tags: haskell

I notice that the these two definitions are no where to be found in the most official resource of Haskell documentation:

```
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
data [] a = [] | a : []
```

I checked Hoogle and there are no entries for `data []` or `(:)`. Are these two not supposed to be "normal" function and data type?

---

**Edit**: In the [Haskell 2010 Language Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#dx16-171015), they say that

```
-- The (:) operator is built-in syntax, and cannot legally be given  
-- a fixity declaration; but its fixity is given by:  
--   infixr 5  :
```

But why? Is there a particular reason for this function to be singled out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's built-in *syntax*, not really a built-in *function*.  The function `(:)` is just one of the two constructors of the built-in type `[]`.  However:

- The name of the type, `[]`, is not valid Haskell syntax for a type-name; so it must be built-in syntax.
- Similarly, the type syntax `[a]` for an instantiation of `[]` is built-in syntax.
- The name of the other constructor, `[]`, is not valid Haskell syntax for a constructor name; so it must be built-in syntax.
- The list literal syntax `[ x, y, z ]` is built-in syntax (obviously).

Since essentially everything else about the type `[]` is built-in syntax, the decision was made to make `:` built-in syntax as well, rather than having it be the one exception that actually was a valid name in the language.

Comment: Strange decision, that.

Answer (score 3):

`(:)` is not a normal function, but is one of the two data constructors in the (not valid haskell 98) definition you posted (**Edit** I guess that's arguable since this definition is not real syntax anyway...)

```
data [] a = [] | a : [] a
```

But it does indeed have the type you posted `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`

The definition of lists above is not valid haskell-98 because terms with non-alphanumeric characters denote infix functions, so `[]` can't be a constant data constructor.

The second, debatable reason has to do with `(:)`. In haskell 98 we can have *infix* data constructors, but they must start with a colon. So `(:)` is a sort of special case of this rule.

This special syntax was added so you can get nice pattern matches like `(a:as)`, and so that there's the correspondence between the empty `[]` list and the *other* special list syntax which looks like `[1,2,3]`.